# CancellationToken not working with zero timeout

Tags: c#, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I have a code which depends on a cancellation token with zero timeout to bail out early. This is the snippet

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        void DoIdleWait(TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var linkedCancellationTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);
            linkedCancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter(timeout);

            while (!linkedCancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting");
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var prog = new Program();
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            prog.DoIdleWait(TimeSpan.Zero, cts.Token);
        }
    }
}
```

Since the timeout is zero, I expect it not to enter the if block, but it's not doing that. Any idea why this is happening? Also, any way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To paraphrase the question:

> Why, when you create a linked `CancellationTokenSource` from a
> `CancellationTokenSource` with a registered *timeout*, then set the resultant *token source* with a *timeout* of zero, does it not know it
> should be cancelled?

More paraphrasing:

> After all, zero is zero and it should know it's cancelled.

The answer is, because a `CancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter` tries to register a timer callback, which attempts to set the resolution to zero milliseconds which it cannot possibly honor.

So in turn, you get the minimum resolution any standard timing mechanism can give you without using CPU spins, which is about 5+ milliseconds.

There are likely other solutions to your problem, however, in short you can't rely on a `0` second timeout to give you immediate confirmation via `IsCancellationRequested`. You will need to rethink your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. The code which checks the cancellation token is owned by a different party, that's why I was trying to bail out early by passing the zero timeout. I will try to rethink the problem since that will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The [`CancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancelafter) method ([source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/threading/CancellationTokenSource.cs.html#1bf5ec1912de006c)) does not include a special handling for the `TimeSpan.Zero` value, so the cancellation is scheduled to the `ThreadPool` with a `Timer` having zero timeout. This results to a race condition, which the synchronous `while (!linkedCancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)` loop wins most of the time. The only solution I can think of, taking into account that the  implementation of the `DoIdleWait` method is not under your control, is to not invoke this method if you know that the timeout is zero.